# Authentification for SPA & API with Mongo DB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, authentication, single-page-application

I have an SPA based on Angular and an ASP .NET Core API. My app uses data stored on Mongo Db Atlas.

I would like to authentify my users. I thought about using the Mongo Db Atlas App Services. That means that my users would be stored on Mongo Db side.

Is it a good idea to delegate this authentication part to MongoDb or could it be done differently ? In fact, I want to use the MFA, mailing & monitoring part already handled by Mongo Atlas and I cannot seem to find any other solution.

I have already tried ASP .NET Core Identity but it seems so "hand-crafted" especially for MFA.
Do you have any ideas, please ?
Thanks

Comment: Advice is not to hand craft authentication/authorization mechanism. There are many considerations and pitfalls. Since you are on Windows, use platform specific mechanism, e.g. integration with AD through. Integrating with MFA could be difficult initially but will be a good idea in this case.

Comment: do you think that IdentityServer would adress these constraints ? Combined with ASP .NET Core Identity or is it disproportionate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally used AAD B2C and not the MongoDb App Services.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).